# How to fix messed-up MacBook disk partition table?

Tags: macbook-pro, partition

I have broken the disk of my Mac doing partitions with `gparted`. Now, nothing boots (except pendrives) and the OS X Rescue Disk recognizes the disk as `Virtual Whole Disk`. Nothing works, repairing or partitioning the disk throws errors.

Is there a Linux utility to reformat the disk completely as I could reinstall Mac OS X? It is extremely urgent, I am extremely nervous because it is for work, and I really don't know what to do. I do not need to recover data, just reinstall.

Comment: Why not boot to the recovery HD and reinstall? Why involve linux when the Mac can repair itself with no outside tools or cables other than power and internet.

Comment: The utility is not able to format the disk. Throws error constantly :(

Comment: ok, solved the problem: I created a gparted live cd, format al the partitions as HFS+, and then the os x recovery utility could recognize the disk. :)

Comment: Please self-answer this. Your solution will help others :-)

Comment: I am currently re-installing the OS X. If the process can finish correctly, I will post the answer. I want to ensure that I really found a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Boot into the mac's recovery, and reinstall (or repair) the drive.

Comment: It is not working. The utility is not able to recognize the disk as it was broken with GParted (I guess).

Comment: @Gab oops, sorry for my ignorance!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, solved the problem. I used a GParted Live USB, re-formatted the partitions as HFS+, and then used OS X on USB to remove all the partitions a create a new one.